# BULK COLLECT INSERT and after checking duplicates

Tags: oracle, plsql

In plsql i want to insert around 1 million rows  from a staging table to actual table and currently I am using cursor for loop for that.
But I understand that there is a way to speed up this using bulk insert for all command but i am struggling in the section of eliminating duplicates. Can u please help to convert the below code to use bulk collect

```html
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 is
    select  
        ps_item_code,
        item_code,
        cons_date,
        shop_code,
        dept_code,
        class_code,
        sub_class_code,
        supl_code,
        plu_price,
        sal_qty,
        sal_val_in_lc,
        disc_val_in_lc,
        tax_val_in_lc,
        odept, oclass, osubclass
    from
        sales_stage;
BEGIN
    FOR i in c1 loop
        BEGIN
            my_cnt := 0;
            select count(1) into my_cnt from hps_ps_terr_sales_1415 
            where  item_code=i.item_code and cons_date=i.cons_date and shop_code=i.shop_code and sal_qty=i.sal_qty and supl_code=i.supl_code; 
            IF my_cnt = 0 THEN
                BEGIN
                    insert into sales_actual
                        ( 
                        ps_item_code,
                        item_code,
                        cons_date,
                        shop_code,
                        dept_code,
                        class_code,
                        sub_class_code,
                        supl_code,
                        plu_price,
                        sal_qty,
                        sal_val_in_lc,
                        disc_val_in_lc,
                        tax_val_in_lc, odept, oclass, osubclass, 
   dept, class, subclass
                        )
                    values
                        (
                        i.terr_code, 
                        i.ps_item_code,
                        i.item_code,
                        i.cons_date,
                        i.shop_code,
                        i.dept_code,
                        i.class_code,
                        i.sub_class_code,
                        i.supl_code,
                        i.plu_price,
                        i.sal_qty,
                        i.sal_val_in_lc,
                        i.disc_val_in_lc,
                        i.tax_val_in_lc, i.odept, i.oclass, i.osubclass,
                        i.dept_code,
                        i.class_code,
                        i.sub_class_code
                        );                            
                END;
            END IF; 
        END;
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, you really don't have any reason to use PL/SQL. The following should accomplish the same end result as your current code.

```
INSERT INTO sales_actual
   (ps_item_code
   ,item_code
   ,cons_date
   ,shop_code
   ,dept_code
   ,class_code
   ,sub_class_code
   ,supl_code
   ,plu_price
   ,sal_qty
   ,sal_val_in_lc
   ,disc_val_in_lc
   ,tax_val_in_lc
   ,odept
   ,oclass
   ,osubclass
   ,dept
   ,class
   ,subclass)
   SELECT i.terr_code
         ,i.ps_item_code
         ,i.item_code
         ,i.cons_date
         ,i.shop_code
         ,i.dept_code
         ,i.class_code
         ,i.sub_class_code
         ,i.supl_code
         ,i.plu_price
         ,i.sal_qty
         ,i.sal_val_in_lc
         ,i.disc_val_in_lc
         ,i.tax_val_in_lc
         ,i.odept
         ,i.oclass
         ,i.osubclass
         ,i.dept_code
         ,i.class_code
         ,i.sub_class_code
     FROM sales_stage i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
          (SELECT NULL
             FROM hps_ps_terr_sales_1415 t
            WHERE t.item_code = i.item_code
              AND t.cons_date = i.cons_date
              AND t.shop_code = i.shop_code
              AND t.sal_qty = i.sal_qty
              AND t.supl_code = i.supl_code);
```

Are you doing more processing than this in the actual code?

Comment: thanks bro...there was a typing mistake in the given sample  code from my side..hps_ps_terr_sales_1415 --->sales_actual....so same out put it will produce?